# Seeking help on Regular expression

Tags: regex, linux

How can I extract this string from the text using regex

text: `{abcdefgh="test-name-test-name-w2-a"} 54554654654 .654654654`

Expected output: `test-name-test-name-w2`

Note: I tried this `"([^\s]*)"` and the output is `test-name-test-name-w2-a`. But need the output as I mentioned just above.

Comment: What is your condition here and which tool / programming language do you use? Additionally show some more input samples.

Comment: What is the pattern here? Exclude `-a` from the end? Exclude `-` and a single character? Exclude everything after the last `-`? Something else?

Comment: @Jan it can be based on PCRE or GOLang. I just need a generic one. Between I am not that familiar with. Basically I need to eliminate letters from last - including -.

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim You say in Linux, what tool do you consider? Perl, sed, awk,  any of them? I'd use `sed`, `sed -n 's/.*"\([^{}"]*\)-.*/\1/p' <<< "$text"`, or awk: `awk -F'"' '{sub(/-[^-]*$/,"", $2); print $2}' <<< "$text";`, or even Bash regex matching.

Comment: From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extend the negated character class to also exclude `-` and `"`. Then use a repeating pattern using the same character class preceded with a `-`

The value is in the first capturing group.

```
"([^\s-"]+(?:-[^\s-"]+)*)-[^\s-"]+"
```

- `"` Match a `"` char
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s-"]+` Match 1+ times any char except `-` `"` or a whitespace char
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `[^\s-"]+`Match 1+ times any char except `-` `"` or a whitespace char
  - `)*` Close non capturing group, repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close capture group
- `-[^\s-"]+` Match 1+ times any char except `-` `"` or a whitespace char
- `"` Match a `"` char

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/jT5TZF/1)

<sup>(On regex101 at the FLAVOR panel you can switch between PCRE and Golang)</sup>

**Update**

To match where the word `test` is present and not for example `test1` you could use a negative lookahead `(?![^"\s]*\btest\w)` to assert no presence of  test followed by a word character.

```
""(?![^"\s]*\btest\w)([^\s-"]+(?:-[^\s-"]+)*)-[^\s-"]+""
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/whLGoI/1)

Comment: Hi, This works. Can you please suggest me how to do this with the below scenario.

Text: 
abcdefgh="test-name-test-name-w2-a.example.com"} 54554654654 \n
abcdefgh="test-name-test-name-w2-b.example3.com"} 54554654654 \n
abcdefgh="test-name-test1-name-w2-a.example2.com"} 54554654654 \n

After applying the regex I should get the below output

test-name-test-name-w2

Meaning only text matching a word only "test".

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim So the current pattern works for that example string https://regex101.com/r/zOlDnB/1 Is that not correct?

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim If you want the word `test` only you could split the match on a hyphen and filter the parts. A PCRE pattern could be for example https://regex101.com/r/pREg4v/1 or https://regex101.com/r/9JgV7Y/1

Comment: Hi @The fourth bird, my intention is not just extracting the word test. As I have given in the example I just need to get the value for abcdefgh only if the value contains test but not test1.

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim I have added an update to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this regex

```
.*\"(.*)-.*\".*
```

The link to regex101 is [test](https://regex101.com/r/GWErZ0/1)